# Как принято говорить о своей специальности?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Справедливо ли выражение "Я из композиторского отделения (отдела)", или слово специализация единственно верное?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Кому говорить? Друзьям в компании? потенциальному работодателю? писать в автобиографии? и так далее... Композиторское отделение (отдел) действительно существует? Мы ж таких тонкостей не знаем...

Comment: Просто в обывательской среде. Мы обычно, когда заполняем какие-н анкет, используем только слово "специализация", она является составляющей факультета "историко-теоретико-композиторского". Но является ли специализация также отделением (отделом) или чем-то еще? Если да, то в чем отличие между вариантами?

Comment: В обывательской - епархия.

Comment: Если говорить, то можно сказать, что "композитор-теоретик", а то не поймут и будут переспрашивать, а если писать в документах, то напечатанное сложное.

Answer (score 0):

Одной из специальностей студентов «факультета "историко-теоретико-композиторского"» вероятно будет Специальность «Композиция».

> Редкая специальность, представленная всего в четырёх вузах России. Во
>   время обучения студенты учатся сочинять музыку к фильмам и спектаклям,
>   песни для эстрадных исполнителей, оркестровые композиции.

https://www.ucheba.ru/for-abiturients/speciality/118